# cocos2dx c++ looping through cocos2d::Vector

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Hi am kind of new to c++ and cocos2dx. am trying to do the following:

```
//MainScene.cpp
Vector<String> frames;
frames.pushBack("ground");
frames.pushBack("sky_bg");

for each (String sprite_name in frames)
{

}
```

this gives the following error in vs2012

> a 'for each' statement cannot operate on an expression of type "cocos2d::Vector

So how should I be going about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct way to use it like :

```
for (const String& sprite_name : frames) {
    // You code
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vikas-patidar this works, But could you explain why do I need to delcare const and use the referto(&) symbol for this to run correctly?

Comment: You can use like `for (String sprite_name : frames)` if you don't need a reference value.